Adding ACF Block Using block.json - Displaying The Preview Hover Image
ACF support have asked that I render my blocks their preffered way... adding this;
function register_acf_blocks() {
    register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/blocks/primary-thin-banner');
}
add_action('init', 'register_acf_blocks');


To my functions.php and then putting each .php template file into their own individually named folders, within a folder called BLOCKS and within, add a block.json file like this;
{
    "name": "acf/primary-thin-banner",
    "title": "Primary Thin Banner",
    "description": "To add a thin banner. Can be used on any page.",
    "category": "formatting",
    "icon": "align-pull-left",
    "keywords": ["page", "post", "primary", "thin", "banner"],
    "acf": {
        "mode": "edit",
        "renderTemplate": "primary-thin-banner.php"
    },
    "supports": {
        "align": false,
        "anchor": true,
        "customClassName": false,
        "jsx": false,
        "multiple": true,
        "mode": true,
        "inserter": true
    },
    "example": {
        "attributes": {
            "title": "Example Title",
            "description": "Example description text that displays in the preview.",
            "backgroundImage": "https://url-to-the-image.jpg"
        }
    }
}

Everything has worked fine ALTHOUGH now my HOVERS over the Inserter icons don't work. Ive added the code that used to render these, into my new block.json file, (example / attributes) but it now doesn't work like it used to. And none of the advice I'm reading in forums is addressing this new preferred method using block.json, everything references the older way to solve this.
What is best practice now to make this happen?
And what json needs adding?

I've finally added my ACF blocks the correct way and pulled through my preview image for the Large ACF Block Preview and for the small Inserter Hover Preview.
See the ACF documentation for this;
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-your-first-acf-block/
1) Add this to functions.php

function register_acf_blocks() {
    register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/blocks/example-block');
}
add_action('init', 'register_acf_blocks');



Put your .php block template (example-block.php) in a folder named the same (example-block) and place within a folder called blocks in the theme files.

In the folder (example-block), put a block.json file to handle configuring the block. This is how I've configured mine. Note the "example" json (that I was struggling with), that pulls through the hoverable Inserter Image.



{
    "name": "acf/example-block",
    "title": "Example Block",
    "description": "To add an example block.",
    "category": "formatting",
    "icon": "align-pull-left",
    "keywords": ["page", "post", "example"],
    "acf": {
        "mode": "edit",
        "renderTemplate": "example-block.php"
    },
    "supports": {
        "align": false,
        "anchor": true,
        "customClassName": false,
        "jsx": false,
        "multiple": true,
        "mode": true,
        "inserter": true
    },
    "example": {
        "attributes": {
            "mode": "preview",
            "data": {
                "_is_preview": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}


Finally create a preview image 1500x844px for the block and add it to a folder in your theme assets.
Then add the following to the top of your (example-block.php) template, (being sure to create the correct image path) and when saved, both preview images large and small hoverable, should work perfectly.

// Check For A Preview Image
if (!empty($is_preview) || !empty($block['data']['_is_preview'])) { 
    // Define Styles Based On Context (Modal vs. Main Preview)
    $block_figure_style = !empty($block['data']['_is_preview']) 
        ? 'width: 450px;'  // Specific Width For Modal Preview
        : '';               // Default Styling For Main Preview
?>
<!-- Block Preview Image -->
<figure style="<?php echo esc_attr($block_figure_style); ?>">
    <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="<?php echo esc_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/img/blocks/p-thin-banner-preview.jpg" alt="<?php echo esc_attr('Preview of the primary thin banner block.'); ?>">
</figure>
<?php return;
}


